# MySQL password checker

Tags: php, database, string

My issue:

I have a password checker that makes sure the password isn't >25 or <5 chars before it's inserted into the database. If it is, it spits out an error. That all works perfectly, however I cannot seem to get it to check if the password is not <5 and or >25 chars and then put it into the database.

The section of code:

```
if (strlen($pswd)>30) {
echo "Your password is too long! Password's should be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}

if (strlen($pswd)<5) {
echo "Your password is too short! Password's should be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
}

else if (!strlen($pswd)>30||strlen($pswd)<5)
{
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
die("<h2>Welcome to M8Ster</h2>Please login to your account to get started ...");
}
```

Comment: Don't do that: Accept any password (except maybe empty or too simple ones), and hash the password before storing it. Not only do you protect the actual password from hacks, providing better safety for your users, but also this will lift the maximum size a password can have.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. Now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Comment: @GolezTrol Don't worry, I've md5'd the passwords before adding them to the database, just removed it to see if it was that causing the trouble.

Comment: @Charles At first I thought you were trolling...then I looked it up. This is going to cut back PHP quite badly.

Comment: @LiamJacobs It's not so bad. Support isn't dropped yet, and you can replace all `mysql_*` functions by `mysqli_*` functions with virtually no other changes needed. It is a good idea, though to not only do that, but also start to use parameters. It is safer and will be faster in some cases too..

Comment: @LiamJacobs md5 isn't the best hash and is easily cracked nowadays, although it may be safe enough for a personal or small business website (I also still use it). Still, matter how you hash it, you won't need the maximum length.

Comment: Given that the deprecation is happening in 5.5 (not even in beta yet), and that removal will happen *no earlier* than 5.6, and given the slow adoption of new PHP versions by most hosting providers (due to slow release cycles by LTS Linux distributions (RHEL, Ubuntu)), chances are that nobody's really going to be impacted by it until 2016, which will have the earliest LTS Linux distros with a candidate PHP version.  All the more reason to start working with the "new" APIs *now*.  `mysql_` has been obsolete since **2004**.

Comment: @Charles, so the reasons to switch away from ext/mysql may simply be the old reasons: it doesn't support prepared statements, parameters, transactions, or an OO interface.

Comment: @BillKarwin, indeed, just now with the added threat that it will *eventually*, years from now, stop working.  The rest of the arguments haven't changed.  It's a double-edged sword.  The removal is going to help developers stop using it, but it's going to make people with old code (and companies that host these people) hesitant to upgrade.  Even then, it's just going to be migrated to PECL, so it can still be *installed*, it'll just continue to be a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

Try combining all the if statments into one if-elseif-else:

```
if (strlen($pswd)>30) {
    echo "Your password is too long! Password's should be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
} else if (strlen($pswd)<5) {
    echo "Your password is too short! Password's should be between 5 and 30 characters long!";
} else {
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$un','$fn','$ln','$em','$pswd','$d','0')");
    die("<h2>Welcome to M8Ster</h2>Please login to your account to get started ...");
}
```

Comment: @LiamJacobs:  If this answer answered your question, please accept it.  That's proper Stack Overflow etiquette.  Click the checkmark to the left of the answer to accept it.